How to Add Owners to Bot in Teams App When Developer Portal Doesn't Reflect Changes?
I have created teams app using teams toolkit. So registering everywhere is done by the toolkit itself. Now I want to add owners to my app and bot. I can add the owner to my app using the developer portal. But there is no option to add owner in the developer portal to the bot. I have mention owner using dev.botframework.com but that is not reflecting into account Please assist how can i do.

You can directly manage the bot owners through the Microsoft Bot Framework portal. Go to Microsoft Bot Framework Portal. Log in with your Microsoft account that has access to the bot. Select the bot for which you want to add owners. In the Bot Management section, navigate to the Owners tab > Click on the "Add Owner" button > Enter the email address of the Microsoft 365 account you want to add as an owner for the bot > Click Save to add the owner.

This document explains how to add owners to an app in developer portal.
